# Using Enterprise Architect VBScript, how do I access an FK connector’s involved columns?

Tags: vbscript, enterprise-architect

I am using VBScript (in Enterprise Architect v15.2.155) to process FK connectors in a PDM and want to access the involved columns (i.e., the foreign key column of the child table and the PK column of the parent table the connector joins). Can anyone tell me if this is possible in VBScript and if so, how?

Have tried a variety of connector properties but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The association is only a part of the FK definition.
The more important part is stored as an operation on your Table element.

In this operation you'll find parameters that correspond in name to the involved columns of the FK.

This code from my [Constraint wrapper](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/Databases/Constraint.cs) lists those columns:

```
    private void getInvolvedColumns()
    {
        _involvedColumns = new List<Column>();
        if (this._wrappedOperation != null)
        {
            foreach (var parameter in this._wrappedOperation.ownedParameters.OrderBy(x => x.position))
            {
                Column involvedColumn = _owner.columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == parameter.name) as Column;
                if (involvedColumn != null)
                {
                    _involvedColumns.Add(involvedColumn);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```